# rewrite_rule for custom post type doesn't affect get_permalink

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type named `course`. I added rewrite rules so I can include post_meta data in the URL.

```
/* Rewrite URLs for generate dynamic template */
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'courses_rewrite_rules' );
function courses_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
    $wp_rewrite->rules = [
        'cursos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$'         => 'index.php?post_type=courses&unity=$matches[1]&formation_type=$matches[2]&courses=$matches[3]',
        'cursos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=courses&unity=$matches[1]&formation_type=$matches[2]&courses=$matches[3]&grade=$matches[4]',
    ] + $wp_rewrite->rules;

    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

It works as expected when I try to access the link through the browser. It also shows correctly in the post editor:

[image: Working here!]

However, if I use the function `get_permalink()` or `get_permalink`, instead of `http://dev.unasp.edu.br/cursos/virtual/graduacao/letras-licenciatura/`, it's returning `http://dev.unasp.edu.br/cursos/letras-licenciatura/0`.

Comment: To customise the permalink, you can use filters `pre_post_link` or `post_link`. look the code here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: I think you'd need to use the post_type_link filter to customise the URL that get_permalink() gets